# In Middleware paradigm, how do you transfer resources from one step to the other?

Tags: middleware

What would be the right way, according to the Middle-ware paradigm/design pattern to transfer resources (like connections to some IO devices).
It is not part of the Request, and it is definitely not part of the Response.
Is there a third object each Middleware step transfers to the next step in line?

The specifics of my question: I am using PHP a FW called TalisMS (which I have full control over). The resource I need to make global for this specific flow is a socket to an external system I need to fetch data from.

The socket can be to different places, and is decided in the first couple of steps, and then I need to continue use that through the entire flow.

I could make some global resource container, I guess, but I prefer something more Dependency-Injection like.

Comment: What is your technology stack and what specifically are your trying to share resources between?  I have a feeling you are thinking about the problem incorrectly, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *The right way would be the way that works*.  I define "works" as "fulfills your software's functional and non-functional requirements."

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I am playing two hats here, I am the owner of the FW which has to remain as neutral as possible to various "business requirements" and in this case, I am actually developing a specific business flow, I am updating the question.

Comment: Well, how do you define "right?"  The only "right" way that I know of is the one that succeeds, in whatever way you define success.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that the "middleware paradigm" (if such a thing exists) does not dictate the manner in which you transfer resources.

Comment: Your edit: now we're getting somewhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This last comment actually defines what I meant by "right", i.e. if/what the paradigm thinks it should be - I usually prefer to use the existing way as a start point. the one about "right"

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I edited with more details.

Comment: Googling FW and TalisMS... neither search result is coherent, even if combined with the term "middleware."  Perhaps you could explain those two terms further?

Comment: I think FW just stands for framework - I was a bit confused about that too. @OP: What do you mean by "Middleware paradigm/design pattern" though - we are probably familiar with the concept but call it differently.

Comment: Just another "everything is a pattern" assumption.

Comment: Found TalisMS [here](https://github.com/itay-moav/TalisMS) - "TalisMS is a PHP framework for fast prototyping systems in a Micro Service ecosystem"; it's owned by the OP

Comment: Why don't you just put your socket into a `Context` object and pass that around, or register it with your DI container as a Singleton?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The idea of Context is more appealing to me, put it as an answer

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - yes, I have stated that in the question I have full control over this FW.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/index.html